Why is a lot of Fourier analysis done on an annulus?
I am studying harmonic analysis from these lecture notes and a lot of results and definitions always assume that the Fourier transform of a function has support in an annulus or a ball. The same hypothesis is also made in many of the textbooks I have consulted.
Is there anything special about an annulus where we cannot just use a ball? Why is it important in Fourier analysis?

@littleO What is the relation between a function's Fourier transform being supported on an annulus and it being periodic?

well, hopefully it’s clear why we might want to assume support contained in a ball (i.e compact support): large frequencies can cause trouble (just like how we generally prefer compactly supported functions over those that are not). As for why we prefer a ‘strict’ annulus, it’s because sometimes zero frequencies are also problematic. At a rough level, it’s just the usual thing that zero and infinity are problematic places. Slightly more precisely, annuli are nice and ‘symmetric’ and concentric, so you can ‘analyze different frequency regimes separately’ more easily (Paley-littlewood theory).

@peek-a-boo Thank you. What is an example of a problem that can occur at zero frequencies? The one that comes to mind is the function not decaying fast enough at infinity. Are there any others?

for instances of where zero-frequencies are ‘troublesome’, just look at the first page of your notes; the Fourier transform of the Laplacian has $|\xi|^2$, so when you divide by it we see the troublesome frequency at $0$. Also, just google zero-energy resonances for a whole bunch of other somewhat related stuff (the study of zero-frequency limits of resolvents is a huge deal in QM and also things like studying various wave equations).

@peek-a-boo It seems you are one step of ahead of me as you just answered the question in my last comment. Thanks again for all the help!

also, another recurring theme in harmonic analysis is ‘chopping up domains’ (be it into cubes or annuli) especially dyadically. This allows for comparable upper and lower bounds. I’m not really sure how best to organize all of these into an answer… hence why I’m merely dumping in the comments some vague ideas (sorry abt that).
